# Log forging prevention with logback

Tags: java, logging, logback, log-forging

How can logback (that uses the pattern layout) be secured against log forging attacks ? Is there a configuration property that tells logabck to escape certain reserved characters ?

PS: The ideal solution would be to decorate each converter with configuration supplied decorator, but it seems to be impossible with current design of logback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the `replace` conversion pattern: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#replace

For instance adding `%replace(%m%ex){'([\\|#])','\\$1'}` to the pattern will escape `|`,`\`,and `#` in the log message and the exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this library from owasp cf https://github.com/augustd/owasp-security-logging/wiki/Log-Forging

Here, a full article to undestand how to use it : https://www.srccodes.com/log-forging-by-crlf-log-injection-owasp-security-vulnerability-attacks-crlf/